# Find one-handed words

Tags: code-golf

'exaggerated' is an example of a word which can be typed on the left hand, on a normal qwerty keyboard map.  'monopoly' is an example for the right hand.

Searching the unix `words` file for words that can be typed on one hand.  Output should be two lines:  space separated list of such words for the left hand, followed by the list for the right hand.  e.g.

```
a abaft abase abased abases abate abated abates abbess abbesses ...
h hi hill hilly him hip hippo hippy ho hokum ...
```

The left-hand letters are:

```
qwertasdfgzxcvb
```

The right-hand letters are:

```
yuiophjklnm'
```

Uppercase letters count as one-handed; letters with diacritics count as two-handed and hence words containing them can be ignored.

Comment: Do capital letters require two hands or one?  I suppose that characters such as "é" cannot be typed with either hand, right?  Finally, I assume apostrophe is a valid right hand key, correct?

Comment: This question isn't self-contained without a definition of left-hand and right-hand letters.

Comment: One thing that might help people using regular expressions: using `[a-gq-tv-xz]` for the left-hand letters and `['h-puy]` for the right-hand letters is slightly shorter than writing them all out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### sed, 78 bytes

```
1{x;s/^/! /;x};/^['h-puy]*$/IH;/^[a-gq-tv-xz]*$/I{G;x};${x;y/\n/ /;s/! */\n/p}
```

requires GNU sed, run with `sed -n -f words.sed < /usr/share/dict/words`

Answer (score 7):

#### Bash (<strike>100</strike> 89 chars)

```
for x in a-gq-tvwxz h-puy\'
do grep -iE ^[$x]*$ /usr/share/dict/words|tr '
' \ 
echo
done
```

Note that 21 chars go to the full path to the words file: if we're allowed to assume that pwd is /usr/share/dict then 16 of those can be saved.

Credit to [chron](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3856/chron) for the shorter regexes.

Comment: "^([$x])*$" should be the regex

Answer (score 4):

### Bash, 86

```
for x in a-gq-tvwxz h-pyu\'
do egrep ^[$x]*$ /usr/share/dict/words|tr '
' \ 
echo
done
```

Taylors `for`, my egrep, chrons grouping of chars.

By definition, if you type by two hands blind, if you like to produce an uppercase letter, you always use the left hand to produce an uppercase character of the right hand and vice versa.

Of course you may produce an uppercase `W` with only the left hand, but you can produce `junk` with the left hand, too, if you like.

Comment: Beat me to the grouping on the letters, good job!

Comment: It's been a race condition between Peter Taylor and me. His 100 (101?) char solution was public, when I started my post and optimization, but he finished his improvement before me, which I observed after finishing my own. I wouldn't have made the post in the same language, just with egrep and without -i, but would have made an comment instead, if he had been some minutes faster.

Comment: I thought about it right after I had made the comment correcting the regex, and left work before I had a chance to do it. Completely forgot about it by the time I got home.

Comment: Your final paragraph is the reason Steven Rumbalski and I pushed for clarification, and the clarification that uppercase counts as one-handed was received more than 24 hours before you published this, so it's not really to spec.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.8 - 126 <strike>135</strike> <strike>139</strike> <strike>144</strike> <strike>152</strike> <strike>137</strike> chars

```
r,a={*"YUIOPHJKLNM'"},'\n'
try:
 while w:=input():
  s={*w.upper()}
  if r|s==r:a=w+' '+a
  if s-r==s:a+=w+' '
except:print(a)
```

**edit:** handle upper case and apostrophe.

**edit 2:** move to python 3. get rid of `' '.join()`. use walrus operator. change `+=w` to `+=[w]` to fix bug.

**edit 3:** change printing to save 5 characters.

**edit 4:** change set creation from `set(iterable)` to `{*iterable}` to save 2 characters twice.

**edit 5:** change two lists to one string to hold result allowing one less assignment on the first line and one less print statement on the last line to save 9 characters.

Comment: Get rid of the for loop and just `print(*a);print(*b)` to save two bytes :)

Comment: @movatica: Nice improvement. Updated answer.

Comment: `s<=r` saves another two over `r|s==r`

Comment: `[w]` -> `w,` save 2 byte. `set(w.upper())` -> `{*w.upper()}`

Comment: set("YUIOPHJKLNM'") -> {*"YUIOPHJKLNM'"}

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae: brackets are required on `+=[w]` otherwise string characters get added individually.

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2.7 (139 characters)

```
import os
a=set("yuiophjklnm'")
c=os.read(0,9**9).lower().split()
print'\n'.join([' '.join(filter(x,c))for x in a.isdisjoint,a.issuperset])
```

Answer (score 3):

### Bourne shell, 55 chars

<sup>(Or any Bourne-like shell but `bash`, `zsh` or `yash`)</sup>

```
w=$1;f()echo `grep -ixe[$1]*<$w`;f a-gq-tvwxz;f h-puy\'
```

Called as `sh -f words.sh /usr/share/dict/words`. (of course, on systems where `sh` is actually `bash` like on some Linux distributions, use another Bourne-like shell like `ash`, `ksh`, `mksh`, `pdksh`, `posh`...)

Answer (score 2):

### Javascript (node), 201 byte

```
f=require('fs');c=d='';r=(a=f.readFileSync('/dev/stdin')+c).split('\n');a.
replace(/[aqzxswcdevfrbgt]/ig,'').split('\n').map(function(k,i){k==r[i]&&(
d+=k+' ');!k.length&&(c+=r[i]+' ')});console.log(c,d)
```

This can probably be rewritten to a much shorter version in another language, but I just wanted to give node a try.

Run with `node words.js < /usr/share/dict/words`

Answer (score 2):

## Q (<strike>121</strike> 140 Bytes)

Output isn't the exact same (backticks instead of spaces) but this is symptomatic of how Q displays string types.

```
i:read0`:/usr/share/dict/words;
0N!/:i:`$/:i where each (min each) each flip i in/:\:(x,upper x:"qwertasdfgzxcvb";y,upper y:"yuiophjklnm");
```

EDIT: Had to handle mixed case, +20 chars

Comment: You can golf this considerably for 111. `\`$'i(&:')(min'')(+)(i:read0\`:/usr/share/dict/words)in/:\:(x,upper x:"qwertasdfgzxcvb";y,upper y:"yuiophjklnm'")`

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby, <strike>112</strike> 92 characters

EDIT: This is shorter, though not nearly as fun:

```
puts %w(a-gq-tv-xz 'h-puy).map{|r|File.read('/usr/share/dict/words').scan(/^[#{r}]+$/i)*' '}
```

Original:

```
puts File.read('/usr/share/dict/words').scan(/(^[a-gq-tv-xz]+$)|(^['h-puy]+$)/i).transpose.map{|w|w.compact*' '}
```

Pretty simple regex-based solution.  As with the others, you could save some characters if you're allowed to pass the filename in ARGV or if it's assumed to be in your current directory.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 130 Bytes

```
a="\n"
b=""
try:
 while 1:v=raw_input();m=[x.lower()in"yuiophjklnm'"for x in v];v+=" ";a+=v*all(m);b+=0**any(m)*v
except:print b+a
```

Run with `python one_handed_words.py < /usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: Am I allowed to take one of the solutions posted here, shorten it, and put it in my post?

Comment: If it's just small improvements, it's more friendly to post comments. If you are making a significant change, it's better to post a new answer, but nice to give credit to the answer(s) you are basing it on.

Comment: [127 bytes in Python 3](https://tio.run/##Dcc7DgIhEADQnlOQaeSTGI0dZE6iFmAwi7IDISy7nB593SujLZluczqEBwHzCMBaHYbxfYkp8KvpGKlsTUi74v04p7yHKmQkGFvMZfl8E60neOfKDx6J96ftGoGDdRq7cimJVVqv8aKUo/GP6iwcr1CaKTVSE147OecP "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [125 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcpLDkMRGEDhuVWICUqbNJ3Rfyed0EhoFblcavX6mJ0vOWU2n9NlLSOtrEBuiUhCZHWNkbmHXPzjGdOLEo7aNhXCw4fo8Fl1CKnsjXE94Hf3U8zDbYxz3QVQTLUR0A9sXKFybf9djwO@Qu59d6WpsoXUmBWGr/UB "Python 3 – Try It Online") using sets

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (191)

```
import Char
g x=all(`elem`x)
f m[]=m
f[x,y](w:ws)|g"quertasdfgzxcvb"w=f[w:x,y]ws|g"yuiophjklnm'"w=f[x,w:y]ws|1<2=f[x,y]ws
main=getContents>>=mapM(putStrLn.unwords).f[[],[]].lines.map toLower
```

Answer (score 2):

### Perl, 72 bytes

```
$a{/^['h-puy]+$/i-/^[a-gq-tv-xz]+$/i}.=y/\n/ /rfor<>;print@a{1,-1,$,=$/}
```

run with `perl words.pl /usr/share/dict/words`

Comment: I get syntax error: Bareword found where operator expected at words.pl line 1, near "tr/\n/ /rfor"

Comment: This works for me on perl 5.14.2, and requires perl 5.14 and up (which is where the non-destructive substitution flag `r` was added)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <strike>26</strike> <strike>24</strike> 25 bytes

```
Øqs€5⁾q'ṭZF€
ỴŒlfƑ¥ƇⱮ¢K€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY4xTsNAFET7fxGfgCNACkRHA93aO7E/Xu9u/t91lJI0qaGiRqIDJCQahEQRRO4RX8QsdDNPM6O5gXObef5@WOm0fT6Zbr9W1fHj5fqsODp@vv/cu@Xhbv902E1vr/vH84Kv5nkeQ2NqB7KsNRxjhCVw26WOOo4x0BDEONZE7DVLC9@AYoi5sIFOFwuyqE2CVEocfEkV3SAmyt5DxrJspDRgeYBPpMZa/K@VnEU0kv64ccRVLrTp2Ld0yb6HpLChmEUzJ1oKQKwOSmv2lj1Uy0O64KZnUB0ENgxUC0xvw9r/Ag)

### Explanation (older version)

```
Øqs€5⁾q'ṭZF€   Auxiliary niladic link
Øq             Lowercase QWERTY keyboard
  s€5          Split each row into chunks of at most 5 letters
     ⁾q'ṭ      Append the string "q'"
         Z     Zip (transpose)
          F€   Flatten each => ["qwertasdfgzxcvbq", "yuiophjklnm'"]

ỴŒlfƑƇⱮ¢K€Y   Main monadic link
Ỵ             Split on newlines
 Œl           Lowercase
      Ɱ¢      Map over the result of the auxiliary link:
     Ƈ          Filter by
    Ƒ             Invariant under
   f                Filtering by the right argument
        K€    Join each with spaces
          Y   Join with a newline
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 243 chars

edit: here's a more compliant program according to the question:

```
import sys
def o(w):
 r="yuiophjklnm'";f=2;w=w.lower()
 for l in w:
  if(f==1)&(l in r)|(f==0)&(l not in r):return 2
  f=l not in r
 return f
y=[[],[],[]]
for w in sys.stdin.read().split('\n'):y[o(w)].append(w)
for i in y[0:2]:print' '.join(i)
```

invoke: `python onehanded.py > /usr/share/dict/words` or any other words file with newline-separated words

old: 141 chars, just a single-word function

returns `right` or `left` if `w` is onehanded, and `both` if both hands are used.

```
def o(w):
 r="yuiophjklnm'";f=2
 for l in w:
  if(f==1)&(l in r)|(f==0)&(l not in r):f=2;break
  f=[1,0][l in r]
 return'rlbieogfththt'[f::3]
```

Comment: Would you kindly turn that into a working program or remove the character count?  Otherwise, the title is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

## Q, 95 (111 with hardcoded dict path)

```
{`$'e[(w(&)l(w)in .Q.a except a)],(e:enlist)w(&)(l:all')(w:(_)read0 -1!`$x)in a:"yuiophjklnm'"}
```

usage

```
q){`$'e[(w(&)l(w)in .Q.a except a)],(e:enlist)w(&)(l:all')(w:(_)read0 -1!`$x)in a:"yuiophjklnm'"} "/usr/share/dict/words"
`a`a`aa`aa`aaa`aaa`aaaa`aaaaaa`aaas`aaberg`aae`aaee`aaf`aag`aar`aara`aarc`aas..
`h`h`hh`hi`hi`hi`hih`hiko`hikuli`hili`hill`hill`hillo`hilly`hilly`hilo`hilum`..
```

14 more chars if you hardcode it

```
`$'e[(w(&)l(w)in .Q.a except a)],(e:enlist)w(&)(l:all')(w:(_)read0`:/usr/share/dict/words)in a:"yuiophjklnm'"
```

Answer (score 1):

## J, 109

```
1!:2&2;:^:_1('qwertasdfgzxcvb';'yuiophjkl''nm')((#@[>[:>./i.)&>/#]);:1!:1<'/usr/share/dict/words'[9!:37]0,3$_
```

I'm sure this can be done better, I don't know how to do string manipulation :-(

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 44 bytes

```
Ljdf.A}RbrT0cQdy."az:ïÑý>Íï“"y"yuiophjklnm'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AUkAtv9weXRo//9MamRmLkF9UmJyVDBjUWR5LiJhejrDr8ORBcO9PsONw6/CkyJ5Inl1aW9waGprbG5tJ///ImFiYmVzcyBraWxvIGEi)

---

```
Ljdf.A}RbrT0cQdy."az:ïÑý>Íï“"y"yuiophjklnm' | # Python 3 Translation
---------------------------------------------+------------------------------
                                             | from operator import contains
                                             | from itertools import repeat
                                             | Q = eval(input())
L                                            | y = lambda b:
 jd                                          |   " ".join(
   f                                         |     filter(lambda T:
    .A                                       |       all(
      }R                                     |         map(contains,
        b                                    |           repeat(b),
         rT0                                 |           T.lower()
                                             |         )
                                             |       ),
            cQd                              |       Q.split(" ")
                                             |     )
                                             |   )
               y."az:ïÑý>Íï“"               | print(y("qwertasdfgzxcvb"))
                              y"yuiophjklnm' | print(y("yuiophjklnm'"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python: 122**

```
import os
S=set("yuiophjklnm'")
c=os.read(0,9**9).lower().split()
print"\n".join(w for w in c if set(w)<=S or set(w)^S>=S)
```

Launched with:

```
python name_of_program.py < /usr/share/dict/words
```

---

The idea is mostly the same of Dillon Cower's, but I use `set(w)<=S` to indicate a subset while `set(w)^S>=S` for a disjoint set.

Comment: The output format is wrong. The words should be sorted by hand.